# How to set a value for a React Context Provider using Hooks

Tags: reactjs

According to the following React Context example, it is the correct way to declare a value for a Provider:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: {something: 'something'},
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider value={this.state.value}>
        <Toolbar />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, I want to know how to rewrite it using Hooks. I have three versions, could you check them and say me what is the correct way or maybe to give me another option.

Version #1

```
export const App = () => {
  const [value] = useState(() => {
    something: 'something';
  });

  return (
    <Provider value={value}>
      <Toolbar />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Version #2

```
export const App = () => {
  const value = {
    something: 'something',
  };

  return (
    <Provider value={value}>
      <Toolbar />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Version #3: a custom version of the #2 using props.

```
export const App = (props) => {
  const value = {
    something: props.something,
  };

  return (
    <Provider value={props.something}>
      <Toolbar />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you look into the npm package `use-global-hook` instead (https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-global-hook). It's a lightweight version of Redux and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState({ something: 'something'})

return (
    <Provider value={{value, setValue}}>
      <Toolbar />
    </Provider>
```

Because you will need a way of updating the value later in ur consumer ( possibly )

Comment: Thanks for you response Konstanitnos Schoinas. In my case, I don't need to update value, so the version #1 would be correct?

Comment: @Aron I believe yes with the only exception, of how you are using useState. Do you want to pass just a value or a function that returns the value ? Apart from that I think you are fine